# Problem retrieving coroutine broadcast message in Activity

Tags: android

In my FirebaseCloudMessaging service, I have to send the remote message to my Activity. I tried creating coroutine broadcast and send the data through the channel. But I am not sure how to retrieve the data at the receiving end which is my Activity class.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    channel = Channel<String>()
    runBlocking {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            channel.send(remoteMessage.notification!!.body.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code that I am using in FirebaseCloudMessaging service class. Can anyone help me out figuring how should I retrieve this data in my Activity class?

Answer (score 0):

Send Broadcast in your Firebase Cloud Messaging class:
For Example:

```
sendBroadcast(Intent("refresh_data").putExtra("data", remoteMessage.notification!!.body.toString()))
```

Create a Receiver to get the data in your activity:

```
 private var refreshReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                val intentData = intent.extras!!.getSerializable("data") as //your model class

                if (intentData != null) {
                    // do your action
                } 
     }
```

}

On your OnCreate() method register the broadcast receiver it :

```
registerReceiver(refreshReceiver, IntentFilter("refresh_data"))
```

now unregister your receiver when you destroy the activity:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (refreshReceiver != null)
            activity!!.unregisterReceiver(refreshReceiver)
```

}